# Which word does with modify here?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I have a question on whether this is grammatically correct :

> .Imagine breaking the door of the man with the hand that feeds you.

The intention is along the lines of "That man feeds you. Why are you biting his hand?"

Does the above accurately capture that, or does it imply you're using the hand that feeds you to break down the door?

Comment: This is called an attachment ambiguity, and is inherent in the structure. _With the hand that feeds you_ **could** be an instrumental phrase meaning 'use the hand that feeds you to break the door' in context. But I don't think that was the intended meaning of the author. The other meaning identifies the man as _the man with the hand that feeds you_, which seems more relevant, if still weirdly metaphorical -- men with breakable doors and feeding hands?

Comment: 'the man whose hand feeds you' would make it clearer.